# Ionic 4: Cordova Camera Preview is hiding html-elements, even though "toBack" is set to "true"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, capacitor

For a university project I have to implement an Ionic App using Ionic 4.

The App is showing locations of Street Art in a Map using Geolocation.

In another menu-tab you can scan a QR-Code, which provides data about a specific Street Art from a .json and displays it in the camera preview using the cordova plugin.

The Scan is working perfectly and afterwards the camera preview is opening, but I cant see the objects from the .html even though "toBack" is set to "true".

I am really stuck with this problem and can't find any solution.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';
import { JsonDataService } from '../../json-data.service';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast/ngx';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CameraPreview, CameraPreviewOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-ar',
  templateUrl: './ar.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ar.page.scss'],
})
export class ArPage implements OnInit {

  datenData = [];
  selectedProduct: any;
  productFound = false;


  constructor(
    private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner,
    private datenService: JsonDataService,
    private toast: Toast,
    private router: Router,
    public navCtrl: NavController, private cameraPreview: CameraPreview, private platform: Platform,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document) {
    fetch('../../../assets/data/data.json').then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.datenData = data.jsondata;
        this.datenService.setJsondata(this.datenData);
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.qrscan();
  }

  qrscan() {
    this.datenData = this.datenService.getJsondata();
    this.selectedProduct = {};
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
      this.selectedProduct = this.datenData.find(daten => daten.qrcode === barcodeData.text);
      if (this.selectedProduct !== undefined) {
        this.productFound = true;
        this.camerapreview();
      } else {
        this.productFound = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab2']);
        this.toast.show(`Product not found`, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
          toast => {
            console.log(toast);
          }
        );
      }
    }, (err) => {
      this.toast.show(err, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
        toast => {
          console.log(toast);
          this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab2']);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  camerapreview() {
    const cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
      width: window.screen.width,
      height: window.screen.height,
      previewDrag: true,
      toBack: true,
      alpha: 1,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      camera: 'rear',
    }
    // start camera
    this.cameraPreview.startCamera(cameraPreviewOpts);
  }
}
```

```css
html, body, .ion-app, .ion-content, .nav-decor {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar text-center>
    <ion-buttons slot="start" defaultHref="/tabs/tab2">
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>ar</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

I would be very greatful, if someone could help me with this issue.

Thank you indeed!

---

**Edit:**

Here is the github repository to it: https://github.com/alexandrasophiapetersen/ARapp.

In Pages/ar is an example QR-Code.

Screenshot of the current page (You can tell, that the html-objects are behind the camera preview):

[image: Ar-Page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** the cordova-camera-preview plugin isn't compatible with capacitor, see: [capacitor/issues/1732](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1732) and [cordova-plugin-camera-preview/issues/563](https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/issues/563)

---

**Old answer:** Did you make sure that your css is actually taking effect and is setting all important layers to transparent?

If you put selectors like `html` in anything but the main app component they won't work out of the box because angular enables [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) by default.

If this is indeed the case you can fix it by either moving the css into the stylesheet of the main app component or disabling [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) for the page in question:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ar',
  templateUrl: './ar.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ar.page.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

---

**Update:** try adding

```
app-ar ion-content {
  --background: transparent;
}
```

the `ion-content` will otherwise hide the live preview:

[image: working preview]

Comment: Hey Fabian, 

First of all, thank you for your answer. 

I have tried both: to disable the ViewEncapsulation and afterwards moving the css into the main stylesheet of the main app component, but unfortunately it did not change anything. 

Here is the github repository to it: https://github.com/alexandrasophiapetersen/ARapp

In Pages/ar is an example QR-Code. 

Also here a screenshot of the current page (You can tell, that the html-objects are behind the camera preview)

[Ar-Page][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiSHa.png

Thank you Indeed

Comment: @Apeter15 Ah sry I concentrated on what looked wrong and apperently didn't realy read what you wrote, that image clarified that though. But... after building your app I can't reproduce the behavior you get, the camera preview is disaplayed behind the html as it should. There is just one more css transparent entry missing, (see updated answer) ... maybe delete `node_modules`, `platforms` and `plugins` and do a clean build?

Comment: Thank you very much! The other problem was, that I was building the app with the capacitor, but after seeing your comments on github, I figured I should run it with cordova and it worked!

Comment: @Apeter15 I couldn't find any hints about how to compile it for android and I haven't used capacitor yet so I just tried `ionic cordova run`. I did some more research, looks like the camera-preview plugin isn't quite compatible with capacitor yet: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1732 and https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/issues/563